# Sort a Drupal 6 view by total flag count for nodes with multiple flags

Tags: php, sorting, drupal-6, drupal-modules, drupal-views

I am using Drupal 6 and have multiple flags on my nodes each with a value such as: interesting, boring, intelligent, funny, abusive, etc. Views is currently able to sort results by the flag count for each individual flag but I need to sort my nodes by the total combined flag count of all the flags on each note. The 'rate' module comes fairly close to doing this but I need to use the flag module so that I can use the flag solr module to allow searching by flag. I just really don't know where to start... any suggestions as to an approach I could take?

Here's the current views query;

```
SELECT node.nid AS nid, 
flag_counts_node.count AS flag_counts_node_count,    
flag_counts_node_1.count AS flag_counts_node_1_count, 
flag_counts_node_2.count AS flag_counts_node_2_count, 
flag_counts_node_3.count AS flag_counts_node_3_count, 
flag_counts_node_4.count AS flag_counts_node_4_count FROM node node  
LEFT JOIN flag_counts flag_counts_node ON node.nid = flag_counts_node.content_id AND flag_counts_node.fid = 7 
LEFT JOIN flag_counts flag_counts_node_1 ON node.nid = flag_counts_node_1.content_id AND flag_counts_node_1.fid = 6 
LEFT JOIN flag_counts flag_counts_node_2 ON node.nid = flag_counts_node_2.content_id AND flag_counts_node_2.fid = 4 
LEFT JOIN flag_counts flag_counts_node_3 ON node.nid = flag_counts_node_3.content_id AND flag_counts_node_3.fid = 5 
LEFT JOIN flag_counts flag_counts_node_4 ON node.nid = flag_counts_node_4.content_id AND flag_counts_node_4.fid = 3 
WHERE (node.type in ('rpodcast', 'upodcast')) AND (node.status = 1) ORDER BY flag_counts_node_count ASC, flag_counts_node_1_count ASC, flag_counts_node_2_count ASC, flag_counts_node_3_count ASC, flag_counts_node_4_count ASC
```

Here the module code so far ;

```
<?php
function flagcountview_views_pre_execute(&$view){
if ($view->name == 'audio') {
$sql = $view->build_info['query']; 
$flag_count = "flag_counts_node.count + flag_counts_node_1.count +  flag_counts_node_2.count + flag_counts_node_3.count"; 
$sql .= "ORDER BY $flag_count DESC"; 
$view->build_info['query'] = $sql;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi seems like you cant add fields, so we can try alternate approach

```
function flagcountview_views_pre_execute(&$view){
  if ($view->name == 'audio') {
    $sql = $view->build_info['query']; 
    $search = "ORDER BY flag_counts_node_count ASC, flag_counts_node_1_count ASC, flag_counts_node_2_count ASC, flag_counts_node_3_count ASC, flag_counts_node_4_count ASC";
    $replace = "ORDER BY flag_counts_node.count + flag_counts_node_1.count +  flag_counts_node_2.count + flag_counts_node_3.count ASC"; 
    $sql = str_replace($search, $replace, $sql);; 
    $view->build_info['query'] = $sql;
  }
}
```

Make sure you added all flag count in view -> sort criteria  :)

Answer (score 1):

considering you already added all flag relationship and flag count in views, it may be good to use views pre execute to add all counts and sort

## Update

hope you already added all flag count in relatioship and fields.. now in code add '

```
function MODULENAME_views_pre_execute(&$view){
  $sql = $view->build_info['query']; 
  $flag_count = flag_counts_node_count + flag_counts_node_1_count + flag_counts_node_2_count + flag_counts_node_3_count + flag_counts_node_4_count; 
  $sql .= " ORDER BY $flag_count ASC"; 
  $view->build_info['query'] = $sql;
}
```

**important**

- make sure you removed all from 'sort criteria'
- make sure you added
  all flag count in 'fields'

Comment: I'm not sure where to start...any chance of some example code?

Comment: I'm not clear on the '<ADD ALL COUNTS>' bit. I tried using; 
<?php function flagcountview_views_pre_execute(&$view){
if ($view->name == 'audio') {
   $sql = $view->build_info['query']; 
   $flag = flag_get_flag('funny') or die('no "funny" flag');
   $flag_count = $flag->get_count($node->nid); 
  $sql .= "ORDER BY $flag_count ASC"; 
  $view->build_info['query'] = $sql;
  }
}

Comment: can you copy your current view query in your question? so i can guide you

Comment: Thanks for your help! I've now added the views query.

Comment: please include all flag count in flag sort, then paste the query here

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this instruction. You mean this?

Comment: yes , thats what i meant .. check my answer i have edited my answer. Also remove newly added flag count from views sort :) (because in code we are adding this ORDER BY) . 
Also include these all 4 counts in fields

Comment: Is there an alternative to adding fields? I am unable to use fields as I am using nodes in an unformatted style with a node-type.tpl.php for each of the node types. Here is the code I am using in node-type.tpl.php to get the flag links on the content; <div class="flag_class flag_funny"><?php $flag_funny = flag_get_flag('funny') or die('no "funny" flag'); ?>
  <?php print flag_create_link('funny', $node->nid); ?><?php print $flag_funny->get_count($node->nid);?></div> Can I use this instead of fields in view?

Comment: why you cant add flag count in view -> fields?

Comment: Do you mean add view -> fields to the node-type.tpl.php ?

Comment: I have updated the question with the current module code which is not working. Though it works ok with just one node count ie:  $flag_count = "flag_counts_node.count;", it does work when I try to add multiple node counts. Would this have something to do with my not having added fields perhaps?

Comment: goto 'admin/build/views/edit/VIEWNAME' , add 'Fields' , now add all flag counts , save the view .. aft

Comment: It's not possible to add fields when you are using 'node' as your row style. Here is the message in the fields area of views; "The style selected does not utilize fields."